# Issue with Calculating SAT Metric in Power BI - Incorrect Aggregated Results

Tags: powerbi

I'm encountering an issue while calculating the SAT (Satisfaction) metric in Power BI. The SAT metric is calculated based on grades received, where grades equal to 9 or 10 are considered positive (Promoters), and grades ranging from 0 to 6 are considered negative (Detractors). The formula I'm using to calculate SAT is as follows:

```
    SAT =
VAR TotalRows = COUNTROWS(ALLSELECTED(SAT_SHEET))
VAR PromoterRows =
    CALCULATE(
        COUNTROWS(SAT_SHEET),
        SAT_SHEET[GRADE] >= 9 && SAT_SHEET[GRADE] <= 10,
        ALLSELECTED(SAT_SHEET)
    )
VAR DetractorRows =
    CALCULATE(
        COUNTROWS(SAT_SHEET),
        SAT_SHEET[GRADE] >= 0 && SAT_SHEET[GRADE] <= 6,
        ALLSELECTED(SAT_SHEET)
    )
RETURN
    100 * (PromoterRows - DetractorRows) / TotalRows
```

However, when I try to create a table, matrix, or line chart to display the SAT results aggregated by location, code, or month, the calculation does not yield the correct values. Strangely, when I manually apply filters in Power BI, the SAT calculation produces the expected results. How can I fix my formula to obtain the desired outcome?

I have a dataset containing the following columns:

| ID TRANS | LOCATION | CODE | GRADE | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | US | RED | 10 | 22/05/2023 |
| 2 | CAD | BLUE | 5 | 23/05/2023 |
| 3 | LATAM | YELLOW | 8 | 24/05/2023 |
| 4 | UK | RED | 9 | 25/05/2023 |
| 5 | US | RED | 5 | 26/05/2023 |
| 6 | CAD | BLUE | 4 | 27/05/2023 |
| 7 | LATAM | BLUE | 1 | 28/05/2023 |
| 8 | UK | BLUE | 0 | 29/05/2023 |
| 9 | US | BLACK | 2 | 30/05/2023 |
| 10 | CAD | RED | 5 | 31/05/2023 |
| 11 | LATAM | BKUE | 10 | 1/06/2023 |
| 12 | UK | YELLOW | 10 | 2/06/2023 |
| 13 | US | RED | 10 | 12/05/2023 |
| 14 | CAD | RED | 10 | 13/05/2023 |
| 15 | LATAM | BLUE | 5 | 4/06/2023 |
| 16 | UK | BLUE | 6 | 1/07/2023 |
| 17 | US | BLUE | 8 | 8/07/2023 |
| 18 | CAD | BLACK | 10 | 26/07/2023 |
| 19 | LATAM | RED | 5 | 8/08/2023 |
| 20 | UK | BKUE | 10 | 22/08/2023 |
| 21 | US | YELLOW | 10 | 13/09/2023 |
| 22 | CAD | RED | 5 | 19/09/2023 |
| 23 | LATAM | RED | 8 | 11/10/2023 |
| 24 | UK | BLUE | 10 | 5/11/2023 |
| 25 | US | BLUE | 10 | 27/11/2023 |
| 26 | CAD | BLUE | 10 | 30/11/2023 |
| 27 | LATAM | BLACK | 8 | 2/12/2023 |
| 28 | UK | RED | 9 | 14/12/2023 |
| 29 | US | BKUE | 9 | 6/01/2024 |
| 30 | CAD | YELLOW | 0 | 12/01/2024 |

To ilustrate my issue let me show you:

When I apply my SAT to a line chart I get this:

[image]

whic is incorrect but If I filter (In a dat filter) my data by month (Mayo) it does give me the proper correct value:

[image]

and the same goes for `location` and `code` I cant seem to find a way to properly show the resulting SAT by `location`, `code` and `date` in a table viz or in a line viz. How can I fix this issue and correctly display the SAT measure over the months, locations and codes of the dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [ALLSELECTED()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/allselected-function-dax) removes the filter coming from the row context.  EG if you write a simple row counting measure like

```
Rows = countrows(allselected(SAT_SHEET))
```

You get

[image]

So try something like:

```
    SAT = 
    VAR TotalRows = COUNTROWS(SAT_SHEET)
    VAR PromoterRows =
        CALCULATE(
            COUNTROWS(SAT_SHEET),
            SAT_SHEET[GRADE] >= 9 && SAT_SHEET[GRADE] <= 10
        )
    VAR DetractorRows =
        CALCULATE(
            COUNTROWS(SAT_SHEET),
            SAT_SHEET[GRADE] >= 0 && SAT_SHEET[GRADE] <= 6
        )
    RETURN
        100 * (PromoterRows - DetractorRows) / TotalRows
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank yu David for your feedback and solution! it worked!